# Laravel cannot find "Class 'Zttp\Zttp' not found" but it is installed by composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am creating a card for Laravel Nova.

I have created a simple API route that will call an endpoint and return a response.

**api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Zttp\Zttp;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Card API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you may register API routes for your card. These routes
| are loaded by the ServiceProvider of your card. You're free to add
| as many additional routes to this file as your card may require.
|
*/

 Route::get('/endpoint', function (Request $request) {
     $response = Zttp::get('https://novapackages.com/api/recent');
        return $response->json()['data'];
 });
```

But when I hit that route I get the error:

> Class 'Zttp\Zttp' not found

This is what my `composer.json` looks like:

```
{
    "name": "jachno/test-http-card",
    "description": "A Laravel Nova card.",
    "keywords": [
        "laravel",
        "nova"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.0",
        "kitetail/zttp": "^0.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Jachno\\TestHttpCard\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Jachno\\TestHttpCard\\CardServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

This must be something obvious, I have based what I am doing on this repo

https://github.com/tightenco/nova-package-discovery

and that is doing almost exactly what I am doing. I say almost as there must be some difference but I can't find it.

I have also posted [a complete repo](https://github.com/jachno/TestHttpCard) including the vendor dir etc.

Comment: Have you installed it? `composer update`

Comment: yep and ran it in the main root as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing your [`composer.lock`](https://github.com/jachno/TestHttpCard/blob/master/composer.lock), I'm sure you are doing `composer update` on your package.

Try to `composer update` from your Laravel project, not from your package.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.